# Extending and displaying an array in asyncstorage in React-native

Tags: javascript, json, database, react-native, asyncstorage

I'm trying to add user-input to a specific array inside AsyncStorage. I am not sure if my current code is doing this. I can't display it via "alert()" and currently I am receiving this error :
`the bind value at index 1 is null"`

```
async addAvailableActivity(){
  try {
    AsyncStorage.getItem('availableActivities')
    .then(activities => {this.availableActivities = JSON.parse(activities)})
  } catch (error) {
    alert('Couldnt load activities!')
  }

  let newActivity = this.state.newActivity
  this.availableActivities.push(newActivity)

  try {
    AsyncStorage.setItem('availableActivities', JSON.stringify(this.availableActivities))
  } catch (error) {
    alert('Couldnt add activity!')
  }

}

async displayAvailableActivities(){
  AsyncStorage.getItem(this.availableActivities).then(activities => {alert(activities)})    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a few problems with your code, first I would store `availableActivities` in your component state if you want to scope it like that. Second, when you call a function `async` you should be using `await` for your promises, third and most important `AsyncStorage.getItem(this.availableActivities)` this seems like a typo, but `AsyncStorage` key value pairs *must* be strings.

Here is an update to your code that I think will provide the functionality you're looking for:

```
addAvailableActivity = async () => {
  try {
    let activities = await AsyncStorage.getItem('availableActivities')
    let { newActivity } = this.state
    if (activities != null) {
      activities = JSON.parse(activities)
      activities.push(newActivity)
      await AsyncStorage.setItem( 'availableActivities', JSON.stringify(activities) )
    }
  } catch (error) {
    console.warn(error)
  }
}

displayAvailableActivities = () => {
  let activities = await AsyncStorage.getItem('availableActivities')
  console.warn(JSON.parse(activities))
}
```

note that I changed the function declarations, this isn't necessary but it prevents them from having to be bound in your constructor. `async / await` is an alternate syntax to `.then` which is much cleaner and easier to read. To check if AsyncStorage returned a value it's best to test it against `null` and finally, I fixed the typo in your last function. Let me know if you have any questions or if I missed the mark

Answer (score 0):

This line

`AsyncStorage.getItem(this.availableActivities).then(activities => {alert(activities)})`

Should be

`AsyncStorage.getItem('availableActivities').then(activities => {alert(activities)})`

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is that you are using an AsyncStorage which cause Async in this way. I think in this way your code will work:

```
async addAvailableActivity(){
  try {
    AsyncStorage.getItem('availableActivities')
    .then(activities => {this.availableActivities = JSON.parse(activities)
    let newActivity = this.state.newActivity
    this.availableActivities.push(newActivity)
   })
  } catch (error) {
    alert('Couldnt load activities!')
  }

  try {
    AsyncStorage.setItem('availableActivities', JSON.stringify(this.availableActivities))
  } catch (error) {
    alert('Couldnt add activity!')
  }
}
```

You also need to use it not exactly after this function. Use it some where else.

```
 async displayAvailableActivities(){
      AsyncStorage.getItem(this.availableActivities).then(activities => {alert(activities)})    
    }
```

**Suggestion:** You can also maintain all your states using Redux. You can also update and access your states from any screen that you want. Here is a good tutorial to help you start it: 
https://www.valentinog.com/blog/redux/

Comment: I've implemented it as this but am receiving only null values, when trying to display the values. This is my input:
'  render(){ 
          <Button onPress={this.addAvailableActivity}
            title="Add Activity"/>}
constructor() {
    super()
    this.state = {}
    this.addAvailableActivity = this.addAvailableActivity.bind(this)
  } 

  handleActivityInput(newText){
    this.setState({
        value: newText
    })
  } '

Comment: @Kokonut:  The reason is that your screen will render before your data retrieve. So you will see null. If I were in your shoes, I put this code in previous screen in the navigation point and obtain the data there. Then pass them to the current screen. In this way you won’t see null any more. Hope it helps you.

Comment: is there a way of centrally storing these values, so they become accesible across all screens even after closing the app?

Comment: @Kokonut: Yes, of course. You can use Redux. It will keep your states and update them from any screen that you want. Its only problem is that, it may be a little bit complex at the first glance. I hope I could help.

Comment: @Kokonut: I have updated my answer, you can check the link and if it was help full, please don't forget to vote it up.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are trying to get an item in incorrect way.

```
async displayAvailableActivities(){
 AsyncStorage.getItem(this.availableActivities).then(activities => {alert(activities)}) 
}
```

First param for getItem should be **string**:

```
async displayAvailableActivities(){
 AsyncStorage.getItem('availableActivities').then(activities => {alert(activities)})    
}
```

[AsyncStorage getItem](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/asyncstorage#getitem)